# Keyboard mapping faulty after water hazard on OS X SL 10.6.8

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Immediately after spilling water on my Macbook (Late 2009 Unibody A1342) it went crazy and made mouse and keyboard input all by itself until I could turn it off.

After replacing the topcase I'm still experiencing major problems though: on trying to enter my password almost all of the keys generate nothing or nothing but beeping.

The hardware is ok: booting into Ubuntu the keyboard works as expected. Logging in into Snow Leopard with an external keyboard and running xev on the Mac shows that the keys are recognized correctly.

Guessing the autarkic input messed up keyboard mapping or deleted some files, I don't have a clue what to do from here. Any help on further debugging actions or actual solutions to this one is very appreciated.

Comment: What is autarkic mean?

Comment: The system did i(npu)t on its own (firing keyboard and mouse events)

Comment: ... I mean does rather than is.